# Mirador with React 17 throws errors

Tags: reactjs, iiif, mirador

I am trying to build a React Application with Mirador IIIF Viewer, But it does not seem to work
Codesandbox link here.

https://codesandbox.io/s/mirador-react-example-with-state-subscription-dispatch-forked-93p0fj?file=/index.js

Answer (score 1):

[@keerti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4743297/keerti) there is currently a dependency issue with Mirador that is preventing successful builds, just as you have encountered. The issue is the result of the application not having been updated in some time. As a result, there are a great number of issues to resolve and updates to make to get Mirador into a stable state for supporting current versions of React.

The good news is that work is now underway to tackle that work. Developers from Stanford and Harvard are presently working through the backlog, and you can see the activity through its [code repository on Github](https://github.com/ProjectMirador/mirador). Specifically, you can observe the [React 17 issue](https://github.com/ProjectMirador/mirador/issues/3601) work in progress, but you can also see that issue in the broader context of what it will take to get there on the [Milestones](https://github.com/ProjectMirador/mirador/milestone/32) page.

Apart from Github you can also connect with the Mirador community on Slack through the #mirador and #mirador-dev channels on [IIIF's Slack team](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdGV9QSFo8i2z1R5iIMP7B2JVhS9akHqcykWF5_y4mtWqVrBA/viewform).

I hope this helps!